# ExtJS How to add a custom panel to rowexpander

Tags: javascript, extjs, datagrid, extjs6-classic

Here's an EXTJS rowexpander implementation

http://jsfiddle.net/Litote0707/xPpf2/

When you expand it, you can see the price.

Instead of price, can I show another custom grid something like this?

```
Ext.define('my.app.main.CustomList', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    title: 'List in Rowexpander',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('myStore'),
    columns: [
        { text: 'Name', dataIndex: 'name' },
        { text: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex: 1 },
        { text: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone' }
    ],
    height: 200,
    width: 400
});
```

Comment: It accepts XTemplate, I don't think you can simply put whole component there. This might be interesting https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?150972-Nested-Grid-using-rowexpander-in-extjs-4

Comment: The following example (with fiddle) about nested grid on the walkingtree blog may also help you solve your problem: https://blogs.walkingtree.in/2015/06/30/nested-grid-in-sencha-ext-js/

Comment: In ExtJs 6.2 they added a rowwidget component to add components inside the rowexpander. https://www.sencha.com/blog/announcing-ext-js-6-2-early-access/